# What would be the windows acl permission equivalent of 600 permission in linux

Tags: java, windows, permissions

I am trying to write the equivalent java code for setting 600 permission for a file in Windows. Below is the method I am using:

```
acl.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(
            AclEntryPermission.READ_DATA, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_DATA, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,
            AclEntryPermission.SYNCHRONIZE, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS, AclEntryPermission.APPEND_DATA
    ));
```

I tried to create file using only `AclEntryPermission.READ_DATA` and `AclEntryPermission.WRITE_DATA` but I get access-denied error. 
Unless I add the other parameters listed in above method, file is not being created.

Can someone brief or point me to a resource explaining the other attributes ( I tried to google but I only get the oracle docs link giving a one line explanation of the attribute) ?

Also please tell if I need to add any other parameters from the `AclEntryPermission` enum.

Comment: The 32-bit access mask is divided into generic, system, standard, and specific permissions. The basic equivalent of Unix RWX is `GENERIC_READ` (GR), `GENERIC_WRITE` (GW), and `GENERIC_EXECUTE` (GE). In addition to what you have, generic access also includes `READ_CONTROL` (Java `READ_ACL`). For file access it also includes `SYNCHRONIZE`, and GR includes `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` (Java `READ_ATTRIBUTES`) and `FILE_READ_EA` (Java `READ_NAMED_ATTRS`). WINAPI `CreateFileW` always requests at least `SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access, and most others request at least `SYNCHRONIZE` access.

Comment: Also, unlike Unix, delete access in Windows is not controlled by write access to the parent directory. `DELETE` access allows deleting an individual file or directory. `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` (Java `DELETE_CHILD`) access on a directory allows deleting its immediate files and directories, but not descendants of child directories. `DELETE`, `WRITE_OWNER`, `WRITE_DAC` access are normally included in `GENERIC_ALL` (GA) access, and for files GA also includes `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` access. This is typically called "full control".

Comment: You didn't specify the security principal you're setting this entry for, but the equivalent security principal for setting owner permissions in Windows Vista and later is "OWNER_RIGHTS". Note that assigning explicit owner permisssions overrides the implicit `WRITE_DAC` access (Java `WRITE_ACL`) of the owner, so be sure to include this right if the owner should be allowed to modify the permissions. Also include other generic-all access that you deem appropriate such as `WRITE_OWNER`, `DELETE`, and `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` (Java `DELETE_CHILD`).

Comment: Also, if the creator of the file is an elevated or non-restricted administrator, by default the file owner is the "Administrators" group. In this case "OWNER_RIGHTS" affects all administrators and doesn't apply when the current user isn't elevated, unless it's a deny entry. This is probably the desired result for a file created in an administrator security context (like creating a file as "root" in Unix via `sudo`), but it may be incidental. If the current user should always have access, make sure to either change the owner in this case, or add an entry for the user.

Comment: @ErykSun thankyou for the response. So if I add `Read_ACL` , `READ_ATTRIBUTES`, `READ_NAMED_ATTRS` would it be equalent to a typical 600 permission? (excluding the OWNER and DELETE permissions you mentioned in other points which I will look into)

Comment: Yes if we grant certain qualifications. With `0600` in Unix we're setting the owner permissions, which apply to whichever security principal happens to own the file when it's accessed. The owner can change (e.g. Unix `chown` or Windows icacls.exe or takeown.exe). The equivalent in Windows is an entry for "OWNER_RIGHTS", in which case normally we should also include `WRITE_DAC` access (Java `WRITE_ACL`). Regarding delete access, setting `0600` on a directory in Unix allows deleting files in the directory. In Windows this is a separate `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` right (Java `DELETE_CHILD`).